# JsonConverter to create field to specify serialized C# type

Tags: json.net

```
public class Foo {}
public class Bar : Foo {}

Foo foo = new Bar();

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

I want the json object to contain a special field which holds the type of the class being serialised.

```
{
   type: 'Bar'
}
```

How do I do this with Json.Net?

Answer (score 0):

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/11/19/json-net-4-0-release-4-bug-fixes.aspx

Still looking for a way to change the name of the property ('$type') and configure which types to export this field for.